# How can I use AES-NI intrinsics on a Mac?

Tags: xcode, gcc, aes, sse, llvm-gcc

I'm trying to compile a C application on a Mac. I use SSE4 and  AES-NI intrinsics.

In Linux, I just call gcc with the -msse4 and -maes flags and include the *wmmintrin.h* header and I can call SSE intrinsics like `_mm_add_epi64(a,b)` or AES-NI intrinsics like `_mm_aesenc_si128(a, b)` and everything works fine.

On the Mac, it's harder, because Apple replaces GCC with llvm-gcc which does not support AES-NI yet. So SSE4 intrinsics work fine, but not the AES ones.
Even inline assembly calls to the AES instructions are not recognized.

Intel has [lots of AES example code](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-instructions-aes-ni/) on their website, but it's for Linux and Windows only.

I did notice the RDRAND instruction is also unsupported by llvm-gcc but Intel provides a workaround for that by using a C macro which expands into raw machine byte code. ([See the rdrand.h example file in this Intel library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/user-manual-for-the-rdrand-library-linux-version))

Unfortunately there is no similar provided workaround for the AES-NI instructions, probably because the instructions have arguments and can't be evaluated as static machine code bytes.

Programs do exist that use AES-NI on the Mac, including Apple's own File Vault, so there must be some method that works!

To make my question concrete, how would I get the following simple call to compile using the latest Mac gcc-llvm 4.2 (latest public release in Mountain Lion xcode 4.4.1):

```
 __m128i A, B, C;
  /* A, B, C initialized here... */
  A = _mm_aesenc_si128(B, C);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should be using [clang](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CompilerTools/Conceptual/LLVMCompilerOverview/_index.html), *not* `gcc`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple developer support reported that it wasn't possible using Xcode. (And in fact their reply was a bit snarky and implied that AES-NI wasn't something a developer ever needed to use directly, so I shouldn't bother. Sigh, thanks, Apple.)

However, I did find two working solutions, both by simply avoiding Apple's software. One is to use Intel's own commercial C++ compiler.
The other is to download and compile GCC 4.6 or 4.7 from source and use it directly.  This is the option I chose. I followed [this guide.](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/02/20/living-on-the-edge-building-gcc-4-7-on-mac-osx-lion/) The GCC compile and install (while clean) is still a hassle and workaround just to use a single CPU intrinsic, but it works.   Thanks, GCC team!

Comment: This answer has changed as it is possible with modern Xcode (4.6.3), regardless of Apple.

Comment: asm volatile ("aesenc ...." : ... ); // works on both llvm and gcc-4.4+, be sure to first check  CPUID.01H:ECX.AESNI[bit 25] = 1

Comment: The takeaway is be vigilant about crypto, whether high- or low-level, as it only takes one subtle coding mistake to expose a large attack surface.